# Casting usercontrol text box to web control text box

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

I have got the following user control:

```
<uc1:TextSearch runat="server" ID="tsClientName" HistoryQueryStringParameter="CN" LabelText="Client Name" />
```

I am trying to retrieve value of tsClientName field with the following code

```
TextBox txtbox = (TextBox)pnlAdvancedSearch.FindControl("tsClientName");
string var = txtbox.Text.ToString()
```

but I get this error:

```
Unable to cast object of type 'ASP.usercontrols_gridviewsearch_textsearch_ascx' to type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox'
```

the user control field got the following code

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txt" MaxLength="20" CssClass="title" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the textbox control from user control as follows:

```
TextBox txtbox = (TextBox)pnlAdvancedSearch.FindControl("tsClientName").FindControl("txt");
```

Comment: thanks, i am not getting the error but nothing gets populated either, i am trying to supply the value to url but the var deosnt get populated   lnkPlanned.NavigateUrl = string.Format("~/folder/page.aspx?state=value1&CN={0}", var);

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to use `FindControl` and casting for access such as this. In the code-behind of the usercontrol, add a property to retrieve the text:

```
public string NameText { get { return txt.Text; } }
```

Then, in the page that hosts the usercontrol, you can obtain the text using:

```
string nameText = tsClientName.NameText;
```

Comment: yes there is TextboxText property on the user control , but still the variable is not getting populated, very strange, thanks for pointing to the right direction though.     lnkPlanned.NavigateUrl = string.Format("~/folder/page.aspx?state=planned&CN={0}", tsClientName.TextboxText.ToString());

Comment: i suspect the user control is missing a set property as i can only see get property ................................................ public String TextboxText
        {
            get { return txt.Text; }
        }

Answer (score 1):

So there is a `TextboxText` property, and it has a `get` accessor. That should be sufficient, as you're expecting to get the input from the user typing into the textbox.

Since the value of the `TextboxText` property is blank, rather than containing the value of the textbox—which we can see it's being set to by the property—the problem must be in the code-behind of the usercontrol. It must be initializing the textbox at the wrong time.